# Programatically adding custom filters to post list

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy

[image]

We have this two filters above the post list, one that filters by date and another that filters by category. I would like to add more filters, based on a custom taxonomy I have in my theme. How could I **programatically** do it?

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out in detail how to add filters on the admin area here on this website https://www.sitepoint.com/customized-wordpress-administration-filters/